# For testing a Swift application that pulls from Firestore, how do I mock QuerySnapshot?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a swift function with the signature `func getItem(querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot)` and I don't know how to mock querySnapshot.

[QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html) is a .h file which I'm not too familiar with. From reading, it seems like it's just a [public-facing interface](https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/connection-between-h-and-m-files-in-objective-c-eaf6b7366717) which is used instead of the actual implementation (please correct if wrong). I tried subclassing from this and using that but I'm not even sure where to add test data to it.

```swift
func getItem(querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot) {
    for document in querySnapshot.documents {
        let cost = document.get("cost");
    }
}
```

I'm in the process of refactoring to where I am less reliant on the QuerySnapshot and convert to an Item prior to the call to this method; which would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: Why? If you're using Firebase then QuerySnapshot is a great container for your data Firebase data. What's the use case here? What do you want to do with your data and what's the purpose behind 'mocking' a standard Firebase object?  A typical use case is to read your data as a QuerySnapshot then create your custom classes from that data. If we have have a bit more clarity, we can probably provide a more accurate answer. e.g. creating abstract objects may be totally unnecessary and actually create more complications and make the app harder to manage.

Comment: Hola. Sorry, I forgot to mention the mock was for testing. Right now, I have a few methods that accept in a QuerySnapshot. I'd like to move away from that and do what you mentioned, read in data using QuerySnapshot and create objects from it. I'm playing around with what @Akiva posted and will update.

Comment: ok. You may not need the added overhead of coding and decoding. I find it easier to maintain to just pass the snapshot in an init method of my class and pull the data fro m the snapshot itself. keeps it clean and easily readable and if a node does not have a child, I can handle that directly in the init. If you want an example, add a snippet of your firebase structure and I will throw something together.

Comment: Late response but I ended up going with that you said @Jay. The init method made for a good home.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with testing and Firebase, there doesn't seem to be a lot of great testing infrastructure, especially for unit tests. The best thing to do is to create data objects that abstract away Firestore, use those objects throughout your code (instead of relying on Firestore), and test with that.

One thing that's been useful is [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase), which will let you decode and encode your snapshot into a Codable object. For example, if you create the simple data object

```
class MyDocument: Codable {
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}
```

You can then decode/encode your data using `FirestoreEncoder().encode`  or `FirestoreDecoder.decode()`